# How can I resize my pixmap in GTK2

Tags: c, gtk2, pixmap

I'm maintaining a gtk2-based application which contains a drawing area with a blank pixmap.

On some user interactions, some items (boxes, etc.) are drawn on the pixmap. We have reached a point where the pixmap (which is initialized with a fixed size) becomes too small.

I haven't found a way to resize the pixmap, which seems weird because I doubt I'm the only one with this problem. For instance, if I want to implement a simple Paint-like program, how do I handle the fact that the user wants to change its drawing size?

What's my best bet here?

Comment: A simple google search returned - [gdk-pixmap-new](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/gdk2-Bitmaps-and-Pixmaps.html#gdk-pixmap-new) which takes width and height as parameter. This can be used with [gtk-pixmap-new](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkPixmap.html#gtk-pixmap-new).

Comment: Thanks for answering, @AjayBrahmakshatriya, but I don't see how this helps me. `gdk_pixmap_new()` creates a **new** pixmap. But in my application, I already have a pixmap. I'd like to resize it not destroy and recreate it (the problem is that there are lots of pointer to this existing pixmap, so destroying it is difficult: I have to track all the pointers and make sure to handle this case).

Comment: you can use [gtk_pixmap_set](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkPixmap.html#gtk-pixmap-set) to set a new GdkPixmap of the desired size. You can create a new GdkPixmap and set it. This will keep your GtkPixmap the same.

Comment: If you have references to the GdkPixmap, you will have to update them. There isn't a way around it.